# No bean named [x] is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I've been looking and toiling most of the day trying to get something to work. Here's the situation:

### The Situation

I am working on an audit-trail for a tool we have at work; this tool is used to edit info (such as texts on websites). Right now everything works fine, but there's one teeny issue:
Right now I am storing the user-data (username, password, ipAddress) in a @context-info (MSSQL). This works fine whenever one user is logged in at a time, but this rarely happens

Example:

- I log on
- I edit stuff
- Stuff I edited gets logged under my name
- Someone else logs into the system
- Stuff I edit is logged under this other user's name, instead of my own, because the @context-info changed at login.

### The Solution

A Session-scoped bean that stores local session-data and then passes parameters per Database Query to the Context info through an Interceptor.

### What have I done so far

I am currently following this guide: [Spring Bean Scopes - Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm) for the purpose of getting a Session-scoped bean. I have the following defined in my *support-servlet.xml* (this is where we define beans):

```
<!-- Session Beans -->
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.lcmg.ticket.support.service.HelloWorld" scope="session">

</bean>
```

The *.java* files have been taken from the tutorial, and work up to a certain point. For instance:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("support-servlet.xml");
```

Gave me issues, untill I changed the parameter to

```
("classpath*:support-servlet.xml")
```

And then this happened..

### The problem

The problem lies herein:

```
HelloWorld hwA = (HelloWorld)context.getBean("helloWorld");
```

If I debug and step over this line, I get a ***No bean named 'helloWorld' is defined*** exception thrown at my face as soon as I log into the tool. I have googled, tinkered, and fiddled and now at the end of the day I still have no solution.

So the question is:
How do I get this ***session-bean*** to work?

I hope I have provided sufficient information, but do not hesitate to ask if you need more information.

Comment: What issues did you have with _gave me issues_?

Comment: Do you get any logging messages? Either that Spring lets you know that the bean was scanned, or that it couldn't find it? To be more precise, does this call log anything? `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("support-servlet.xml");`

Comment: does it work if you remove scope=session?

Comment: @arahant Sadly, no. The problem persists.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got a ***File could not be opened because it does not exist*** exception. I even gave a hard-coded string-path like **C:\Users\Me\Projects\...** but that did not work. the ***"classpath*:..."*** worked and removed my error.

Comment: @Magnilex The call logs nothing, for as far as I can see. Though I did notice something about a different bean not being found; but that was from before I joined the company. I might check into that.

Comment: Maybe you need to configure the logging to enable it. Spring typically logs when binding the beans to its context, and might throw an exception if something fails.

Answer (score 0):

So I fiddled around some more and I did this:

The bean definition has been moved to a different .xml (we apparantly had **applicationContext.xml** with other *scope="session"* beans, it now looks like this (I've also changed the name for the implementation etc.):

```
<bean id="auditUser" class="com.lcmg.ticket.support.service.model.AuditUser" scope="session">

</bean>
```

I dumped the whole **applicationContext context..** bit, and instead mapped the bean to a class-bean, like so:

```
<bean name="/historyList" class="com.lcmg.ticket.support.web.controller.HistoryListController">
    /*Other-for-this-example-useless properties*/
    <property name="auditUser" ref="auditUser"/>
</bean>
```

And I could then in my code make a variable **auditUser**, create a setter, and then I did this:

```
auditUser.setSessionUser(sessionUser);
auditUser.setPassword(command.getPassword());
```

And now it works. No more errors, and whenever I call something from **auditUser** it's the same throughout the session.